# ffmpeg timing individual frames of an image sequence

Tags: ffmpeg, format, containers, webp

I am having an image sequence input of webp-s concatenated (for various reasons) in a single file. I have a full control over the single file format and can potentially reformat it as a container (IVF etc.) if a proper exists.

I would like ffmpeg to consume this input and time properly each individual frame (consider first displayed for 5 seconds, next 3 seconds, 7, 12 etc.) and output a video (mp4).

My current approach is using `image2pipe` or `webp_pipe` followed by a list of `loop` filters, but I am curious if there are any solid alternatives **potentially a simple format/container I could use in order to reduce or completely avoid ffmpeg filter instructions** as there might be hundreds or more in total.

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex "...movie=input.webps:f=webp_pipe,loop=10:1:20,loop=10:1:10..." -y out.mp4
```

I am aware of `concat` demuxer but having a separate file for each input image is not an option in my case.

I have tried [IVF format](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=IVF) which works ok for vp8 frames, but doesnt seem to accept webp. An alternative would be welcomed, but way too many exists for me to study each single one and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Despite your `concat` demuxer comment, it seems the cleanest if you just call FFmpeg twice: once to separate webp files to a temp folder and again to `concat` them with a timing text file. Once done, delete the temp folder. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thansk for the idea @kesh . I managed to optimize filterchain from `loop`-s to a single `setpts` with realtively straightforward algorithm `setpts=PTS+gte(N\,10)*25+gte(N\,20)*25` . The other option I was considering is png inside mov container, however I am not sure I can time individial frames inside mov...